# How to find out Union of Dictionary Values in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to find out Union of dictionary Values. I have created the dictionary below.

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
List<string> ls1 = new List<string>();
ls1.Add("1");
ls1.Add("2");
ls1.Add("3");
ls1.Add("4");

List<string> ls2 = new List<string>();

ls2.Add("1");
ls2.Add("5");
dict.Add(1, ls1);
dict.Add(2, ls2);
```

So in this case Output would be {"1","2","3","4","5"}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` you may use Linq.

The following Linq will get what you are after:

```
dict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).Distinct()
```

The `SelectMany` will select all of the elements of the lists, the `Distinct()` ensures duplicate elements are only returned once.

As stated in the comment, you require a `List<string>` of the result, so the code may be extended to:

```
var result = dict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I need to get this into a List<string>.

Comment: Then do a `.ToList()` after the `.Distinct()`

Comment: It does not handle the case If any Dictionary Value is null.

Comment: Then perform a where clause before the `SelectMany`, i.e. `dict.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).Where(v => v != null).SelectMany(v => v).Distinct().ToList()` break this into intermediate variables or multiple lines for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to flatten the values and eliminate the duplicates using `Distinct`:

```
dict.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get union of your values, you could use LINQ Union:

```
 dict.Values.Union(dict.Values);
```